# Work with Symfony In Eclipse using Composer

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, file-get-contents, composer-php

It's been days trying to create A Symfony project using Eclipse PDT with composer feature installed, but an error from composer keeps me from achieving this.

here are the steps i followed to do so:

1. I Installed Eclipse Standard Kepler version
2. I Installed PDT plugin, Symfony, Composer ... and all the stuff using this update site (http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/)
3. I configured PHP executable
4. I create a new Symfony project, but when I click the finish button, I have the following error

[image: Composer Error]

I tracked on the web this error, and found the reason is that the php function : file_get_contents()

I have no idea what to do to solve this issue.

Please help.

PS : by the way i enabled that PHP extension php_openssl and still not workin

Comment: can you successfully create project using command line? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Comment: I guess your local PHP that executes Composer lacks SSL support. Try to run `composer diag` on the same command line and post the results here.

Comment: @Sven You are right there is a problem with the ssl, but i've enabled it in php.ini file, and still no results :/ even retrieving composer using the command line doesn't work i.e. this command : php -r "eval('?>'.file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/installer'));"

Comment: Did you change the right php.ini? There is one separate for the command line version of PHP that is not used for the web server.